# Show only specific information after dropped external event to full calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to hide unnecessary parts after droprd external event to full calendar.
Following is a sample code of a external event.

```
<div class="external-event external-box-job draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-job_id="695" data-job_code="SRTC00695" id="695" data-event="{'title':'Test department 2'}">
    <div class="job-lists">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="emp-name">Test Customer  </div> 
                <button style="background-color: #be0101;color:#fff;font-weight: bold;" type="button" class="btn green-meadow normal-state">Urgent</button>
                <button style="background-color: #d468d0;color:#fff;font-weight: bold;" type="button" class="btn green-meadow normal-state">Approved</button>                                                          
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div class="profile-shedule">
                    <img class="cus_image-pop" src="uploads/customer/1481094745.jpg" alt="...">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <div class="event-sercode">
                    <br><strong style="font-size: 11px; color: #9b9b9b; float: left; width: 100%; border-bottom: solid 1px #dedede; margin-bottom: 7px;">Due Out: 09th Dec 2016 08:06 pm</strong><br>
                    <div class="event-sercode"><strong>Test department 2</strong></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I attached images to show the bug after droped external event to calendar.
[image: Before drop to calendar]

Following is the after drop external event to calendar.
[image: After drop external event]

I need only to show Test department 2 part. But it shows all the texts. How can I hide unnecessary part from this?

Comment: Please give me a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for **[eventReceive](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/eventReceive/)**:

"If done through an HTML5 attribute, make sure it is valid JSON! For example, property names must be enclosed in double quotes! For more information, see parseJSON."

So please try to replace:

```
<div class="external-event external-box-job draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-job_id="695" data-job_code="SRTC00695" id="695" data-event="{'title':'Test department 2'}">
```

with:

```
<div class='external-event external-box-job draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle' data-job_id='695' data-job_code='SRTC00695' id='695' data-event='{"title":"Test department 2"}'>
```